# Show that every ordered set with the well ordering has the least upper bound property

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Here is a proof attempt:

Let $S_a =\{x\in A:x \leq a\}$ (also known as a section of $A$).
 We firstly prove that $\forall a \in A$, $S_a$ has a supremum in $A$.

Clearly, every $S_a$ is bounded above by $a$. We consider $T =A \setminus S_a$. Now, $T$ being non empty [unless $a = \max\{A\}$], it has a minimal element $m$.

Now, $a$ is an element of $S_a$ with these properties:

1. $a$ is an upper bound of $S_a$ and $a \in S_a$ (not strict partial order relation).
2. Any element less than $a$ is not an upper bound of $S_a$.
3. $a\leq m$ and $m\notin S_a$.

Clearly,  $\sup S_a =a$.

We generalise this to the case of any bounded above set $K$.  Let $\max K =M$. The section corresponding to the element $M$, i.e. $S_M$ contains $K$. So, $K \subset S_M$ and $\max S_M = \max K= M$. Now, $M$ is such an element that:

1. $M$ is an upper bound of both $S_M$ and $K$.
2. Any element greater than $M$ is not in the two sets.
3. No element less than $M$ can be an upper bound of either of the sets.

So, $\sup S_M =  \sup K = M$

I don't know if this is a valid proof. A thorough verification would be of immense help.

Thank You.

Comment: Arbitrary $K$ need not have a maximum element $M$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri what if it is not a strict partial order?

Comment: That's not the issue, Let $A = \omega + 1$ and $K = \omega$. Then $K$ is bounded from above, yet it has no maximum element.

Comment: How about the minimal element of the set $\{x\in A : x$ is an upper bound of $K\}$

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas That looks like a better candidate, try working that out. As a bonus you will probably get a shorter and more elegant proof.

Comment: As @ShervinSorouri pointed out, not every upper-bounded set of elements in a well-order has a maximum, so your proof is wrong. More generally, you shouldn't apply operations to anything unless you prove that they can be applied. $\max$ can be applied to finite sets of elements in a linear order. Your second attempt in the comment will lead to a correct proof.

Comment: @user21820 , all I had in my mind while writing this proof was the set of natural numbers, so  a mistake was bound to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a well ordered set.
If $A$ is a not empty subset of $S$ with an upper bound $b$.
Then $B$, the set of upper bounds of $A$ is not empty.
So $B$ has a least element $d$.
If $d$ is a successor, then the predecessor is the maximum element of $A$.
If $d$ is not a successor, then $d$ is the supremum of A.

Comment: I have edited the post a bit. If you disagree with it feel free to rollback.